# FM synthesis in iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

I would like to modulate the signal from the mic input with a sine wave at 200HZ (FM only).  Anyone know  of any good tutorials/articles that will help get me started?

Any info is very welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start here [Audio File Stream Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162)

Here you can also find some basic tutorials: [Getting Started with Audio & Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_MusicAudio/_index.html).
Especially the [SpeakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) example app could be interesting
Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do audio processing in iOS or OSX is Core Audio. Here's [Apple's overview of the framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html).

However, Core Audio has a reputation of being very difficult to learn, especially if you don't have experience with C. If you're still wanting to learn Core Audio, then this book is the way to go: [Learning Core Audio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848).

There are simpler ways to work with audio on iOS and OSX, one of them being [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io/), which was developed specifically so developers can quickly prototype audio without having to deal with lower-level memory management, buffers, and pointer arithmetic.

There are examples showing both FM synthesis and audio input via the microphone, so you should have everything you need :)

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of AudioKit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good job on the CSound wrapper.  I have already built a processing chain with Core Audio and this is the final stage of the signal flow.  I was looking for technical articles and maybe an example of mic input modulated (frequency only ) with a sine wave

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I was reading this as if you were just getting started. My bad; good luck!